# NoMethodError Undefined Method FixNum - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, nomethoderror

I have an agent_review model and an a agent model. In the agent_review table there is a column named "reviewer_id" and that is the id of the agent that reviewed the agent. I am having an issue getting the name of the reviewer from the id. I hope that makes sense. Below is the relevant code. Thanks in advance.

Agent model

```
has_many :agent_reviews
```

Agent_Review model

```
belongs_to :agent
```

Agent_Reviews Controller - Index Method

```
def index
   @agent = Agent.find(params[:agent_id])
   @agent_reviews = @agent.agent_reviews.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

Agent_Review/Index

```
<div class="mega-container"><br>
   <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Agent Reviews</h1>
      <h3><%= @agent.name %></h3>
      <div class="container feedback-index">
         <% @agent_reviews.each do |agent_review| %>
            <div class="row feedback-strip">
               <p>Submitted: <%= agent_review.created_at.strftime('%D @ %I:%M %p') %></p>
               <p>Name: <%= agent_review.agent.name %></p>
               <p class="star-rating" data-score= <%= agent_review.rating %> >Rating: </p>
               <p>Review: <%= agent_review.comment %></p>
            </div><br>
         <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Error

[image]

Schema

```
create_table "agent_reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "agent_id"
  t.integer  "reviewer_id"
  t.text     "comment"
  t.integer  "rating"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`agent_review.reviewer_id` returns a integer(`Fixnum`) and you can't call `name` method on a `Fixnum` object.

And there's a problem with your association since you're not following the rails way of setting up foreign keys. First of all, you've to specify the column that you're using as a foreign key in `agent_review` model.

```
# in agent_review.rb

belongs_to :agent, foreign_key: 'reviewer_id'
```

And then try

```
<%= agent_review.agent.name %>
```

to retrieve the name of the agent from the review.

EDIT

If you want to retrieve information about the reviewee, add a new association to `agent_review.rb`

```
belongs_to :reviewee, class_name: 'Agent', foreign_key: 'agent_id'
```

Now, you can call `agent_review.reviewee` which will give you information about the person who was reviewed.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but what if I need the reviewer's name (which I know have) and that of the agent that they are reviewing? Can you help at all?

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart  To answer that, I need to know the schema of the agent_reviews table.

Comment: I added the schema for the agent_reviews table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart Updated my answer. See if it helps. Also consider upvoting my answer if you haven't already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop first because `agent_review` is not defined in the controller.

```
<% @agent_reviews.each do |agent_review| %>
  # YOUR HTML CODE HERE
<% end %>
```

Also, if that's just because its not included, its probably because `agent_review.reviewer_id` returns a number instead of the actual `reviewer`. Your associations are incomplete so maybe you mean `agent_review.agent`? This should point you in the right direction! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```
agent_review.reviewer.name
```

`agent_review.reviewer_id` is an int (ie Fixnum), while `agent_review.reviewer` is the object you're looking for.

Comment: That just gives me the agent who is being reviewed, not the reviewer.

Answer (score 0):

You agent model has many agent_reviews, so what's being passed to your index as @agent_review is actually an array, so you'd need to loop through that array in your view to access the individual objects which make up that array.